# Moving cursor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form for data entry. The form will consist of 70 items. 
Each response will consist of a single whole number between 1 and 10.
I have created the form successfully, and it works.
HOWEVER, I would like to have the cursor advance to the next item after the preceding response is entered.
For example, if you press "1" for the first response, the cursor will automatically go to the second response. You enter the second response, and the cursor moves to the third field, etc. etc. until you have entered all 70 responses.
The problem is that I do not know how to make the cursor move automatically. I tried to solve this in Excel, gave up, and now I'm trying with Javascript

I found some syntax on jsfiddle.net, and I created the form. However, I don't know how to make it work in Notepad. 
I've pasted the syntax below. The solid line separates what I understand to be the html code from the java. They aren't working together very well in notepad, and I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance for your time. They didn't teach us this in the Marine Corps!

```
    <div class="container">
a: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
b: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
c: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
</div>

____________________________________________________

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
container.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var target = e.srcElement;
    var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
    var myLength = target.value.length;
    if (myLength >= maxLength) {
        var next = target;
        while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
            if (next == null)
                break;
            if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                next.focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the JavaScript code inside an `<script>` tag in the HTML.

```
<div class="container">
   a: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
   b: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
   c: <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
</div>
<script>
   var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
   container.onkeyup = function(e) {
       var target = e.target;
       var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
       var myLength = target.value.length;
       if (myLength >= maxLength) {
          var next = target;
          while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
              if (next == null)
                  break;
              if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                  next.focus();
                  break;
              }
          }
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much! Any idea how I can copy the completed form into an Excel file?